# Restrict HTML files access

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a portal with Login Authentication and after the user login to the website we are providing few links to the HTML files. This works perfect.

My concern is User's are able to access the HTML files without logging to the portal. I will not be able to convert the file to PHP as these files are huge and will be modified and updated regularly.

Please suggest how i can restrict the direct access to the HTML if the user is not logged in.

Tx
Suneel

Answer (score 1):

Use `.htaccess` file to restrict access and authenticate user, then put your HTML files in subfolder related to location of that .htaccess file (so its restrictions would also apply). For example, you create `.htaccess` file with content like this:

```
AuthName "Enter password"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path-to-folder/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

then you create `.htpasswd` files which holds logins and password hashes. It will look like this (one line per user):

```
userlogin:8OytGCYCAPbS6
```

You can use some online `.htpasswd` generators like [this one](http://www.kxs.net/support/htaccess_pw.html)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried using .htaccess file. Can you share me sample code if any??

Comment: I dont think it would be right suggestion for the external users to enter the password for each link.

Comment: there's no "for each link" case

Comment: Sorry No.Actually i dont want the users to prompt with popup for entering username and password as the user will have already entered in php login system. Is there any setting in .htaccess file whether the request came from index.php file or not??